# Light way to updating related data in razor pages

Tags: c#, razor

I have a razor page to update related data:

**.cshtml**

```
@page
@model IdentityServer4.Manager.Pages.IdentityServer.CrudApiResource.EditModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<h4>ApiResource</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="ApiResource.Id" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ApiResource.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ApiResource.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ApiResource.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ApiResource.DisplayName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ApiResource.DisplayName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ApiResource.DisplayName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ApiResource.Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ApiResource.Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ApiResource.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input asp-for="ApiResource.Enabled" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ApiResource.Enabled)
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <hr />
            <div class="row form-group">
                <h4>ApiScope</h4>
                <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="AddApiScope">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ApiResource.Scopes[0].Name)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ApiResource.Scopes[0].DisplayName)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ApiResource.Scopes[0].Description)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ApiResource.Scopes[0].Required)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ApiResource.Scopes[0].Emphasize)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ApiResource.Scopes[0].ShowInDiscoveryDocument)
                        </th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ApiResource.Scopes.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td class="form-group">
                                <input asp-for="ApiResource.Scopes[i].Name" class="form-control" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="form-group">
                                <input asp-for="ApiResource.Scopes[i].DisplayName" class="form-control" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="form-group">
                                <input asp-for="ApiResource.Scopes[i].Description" class="form-control" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="form-group">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input asp-for="ApiResource.Scopes[i].Required" />
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="form-group">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input asp-for="ApiResource.Scopes[i].Emphasize" />
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="form-group">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input asp-for="ApiResource.Scopes[i].ShowInDiscoveryDocument" />
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="RemoveApiScope" asp-route-scopeName="@Model.ApiResource.Scopes[i].Name">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" asp-page-handler="Save" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="./Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

**.cs**

```
using IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities;
using IdentityServer4.Manager.Controllers;
using IdentityServer4.Manager.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IdentityServer4.Manager.Pages.IdentityServer.CrudApiResource
{
    public class EditModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public EditModel(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public ApiResource ApiResource { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int id)
        {
            ApiResourceController apiResourceController = new ApiResourceController(_context);
            var result = await apiResourceController.GetApiResourceFull(id);

            if (result.GetType() != typeof(OkObjectResult)) { return result; }
            ApiResource = (ApiResource)((OkObjectResult)result).Value;

            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSaveAsync()
        {
            ApiResourceController apiResourceController = new ApiResourceController(_context);
            var result = await apiResourceController.PutApiResource(ApiResource.Id, ApiResource);

            if (result.GetType() != typeof(NoContentResult)) { return result; }

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }

        public IActionResult OnPostAddApiScope()
        {
            ApiResource.Scopes.Add(new ApiScope());
            return Page();
        }

        public IActionResult OnPostRemoveApiScope(string scopeName)
        {
            ApiResource.Scopes.RemoveAll(x => x.Name == scopeName);
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Everyting works, but I am new in web developer and razor pages.
To add or remove items I am calling a different post action.
I am wondering if there is a light way to add and remove child items (Scopes in example).

Maybe Ajax or JQuery?

Comment: there are some controls for this, check https://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui

Comment: Corrected grammar, removed duplicate sentences, improved verbiage.